# How to union more than two tables in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-collection

I want to union table questions and choices in query builder JSON Resource Laravel. When I'm trying this I'm getting an error; what's wrong with my code?

This is my CurriculumDisplayResource:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CurriculumDisplayResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {

        $second = DB::table('questions')
            ->join('quizzes','quizzes.id','=','questions.quiz_id')
            ->select('questions.*')
            ->get();
        $third = DB::table('choices')
            ->join('questions','questions.id','=','choices.question_id')
            ->select('choices.*')
            ->get();


        return [

                    'id' => $this->id,
                    'title_section' => json_decode($this->title_section),
                    'learning_objective'=> json_decode($this->learning_objective),
                    'content_detail' =>

                        DB::table('curriculums')
                            ->join('content_texts','curriculums.id','=','content_texts.curriculum_id')
                            ->join('content_files','curriculums.id','=','content_files.curriculum_id')
                            ->join('content_videos','curriculums.id','=','content_videos.curriculum_id')

                            ->join('quizzes','curriculums.id','=','quizzes.curriculum_id')

                            ->select('content_texts.title_text','content_texts.text_course',
                                'content_files.title_file','content_files.file_course','content_videos.title_video',
                                'content_videos.video_course','quizzes.title_quiz','quizzes.')
                            ->union($second)
                            ->union($third)
                            ->get(),


                    'parent_id' => $this->id,
                ];
    }
}
```

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: I suppose the correct title is 'How to union more than two tables in laravel?' Please fix

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `->get()` at the end of your queries if you want to use them in `union()` method.

```
$second = DB::table('questions')
    ->join('quizzes','quizzes.id','=','questions.quiz_id')
    ->select('questions.*');

$third = DB::table('choices')
    ->join('questions','questions.id','=','choices.question_id')
    ->select('choices.*');
```